# ciphertext stealing and CTR

Tags: block-cipher, cbc, ctr, ecb

Why Does CTR mode encryption not use ciphertext stealing?

Answer (score 2):

In [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) mode, the encryption of the counter produces a stream of pseudo-random bits. Encryption is XORing plaintext with that stream of bits, yielding ciphertext (and vice versa for decryption). We do not need ciphertext stealing because we can produce the stream of bits from IV alone: it has no dependency on plaintext; and we can truncate that stream of bits so that its length matches the plaintext.

---

The same reasoning works for [OFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_Feedback_(OFB)) mode. For [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)), the stream of bits is plaintext-dependent, but for the last block it does not depend on the last plaintext block, thus we do not need ciphertext stealing either.

Ciphertext stealing is useful for [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) and [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)) modes, where ciphertext is not the XOR of plaintext and some pseudo-random stream, but rather is an output of the block cipher.

Comment: Thank you for answer which is so kind and well described.

Answer (score 1):

Ciphertext stealing (CTS) enables a block-cipher to process variable-length messages without expanding with padding. CTR does not rely on CTS because it, being a stream cipher, is already variable-length.

CTR does not use CTS because CTS implies a dependency on the previous block, with the initial pseudo-block being the initialization vector.

---

CTS enables ECB, CBC and PCBC to produce variable-length outputs. But their use implies different costs:

1. ECB-CTS: all blocks may be concurrently encrypted and decrypted except for the last whole block and the remaining few bytes.
2. CBC-CTS: encryption is strictly sequential while decryption is concurrent
3. PCBC-CTS: both encryption and decryption are sequential

Meanwhile CTR, as a concurrent stream cipher, does not have any dependency on any other block. This concurrency reduces the encryption and decryption latency, leading to significantly better performance when pipeline optimizations are present - as they are with AES-NI.

Comment: Thank you for answer which is so kind and well described